# How should I interpret $|2\rangle|3\rangle$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am a beginner at QC. I was going through the basics of multi-qubits I encountered a state $|2\rangle|3\rangle$.

I want clarification on the following points:

1. Can I write $|2\rangle$ as $|10\rangle = |1\rangle|0\rangle$ always?
2. If $|2\rangle = |10\rangle = |1\rangle|0\rangle$, Can I write $|2\rangle|3\rangle = |10\rangle|11\rangle = |1011\rangle$?

Assume $|0\rangle$, $|1\rangle$ in computational basis.
$|0\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
    1 \\
0
\end{bmatrix}$,
$|1\rangle = \begin{bmatrix}
    0 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: I've never seen decimal notation like $|2\rangle$; it is not clear whether it means 2-qubit state $|10\rangle$ or 3-qubit state $|010\rangle$ or other multiqubit state.

Comment: @kludg: It is generaly basis vector representing decimal number 2. You are right that it can be $|011\rangle$ as well, however, it should be clear from dimensionality of a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation is right.

1) $|2\rangle$ is $|10\rangle$, or vector $\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ in Hilbert space representing two q-bits system.

2)Yes, it is possible as well. The first two q-bits in in state $|10\rangle$ and last two q-bits in state $|11\rangle$, hence the state of all four q-bits is $|1011\rangle$, or $|11\rangle$ (eleven!) in decimal but I would recommend to avoid writing decimal numbers in this case as they can be confused with binary numbers easily.